# Working with big numbers

Tags: 3d-view, coordinates

I want to extrude a shape from an SVG file, then create its negative (boolean with a scaled cube).

I can do the obvious steps if I scale and move the shape. The real problem is that the SVG file works with big numbers (in the millions). I can not zoom out enough to see the object(s) in their original size but it would be important not to change the coordinate-space.

Comment: Why not scale the SVG down to a manageable size, then apply the scale (Ctrl-A)?

Comment: @CharlesL The object is not centered around (0,0) It is in a different coordinate system, my goal is to use that one in Blender as fully as possible instead of transform -> process -> reverse transform (and hope I got the reciprocals right).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set the *3D View far clipping distance* in the *properties* panel (press <kbd>N</kbd> in the 3D view to toggle it),
**and/or**
the *Camera far clipping distance* in the *Lens* section of the *Camera* tab:

[image]

By the way, it's limited to maximum 10 000 units (or 10Km), so I don't think it'll works nice with objects having scale in millions.

You should consider scaling down the objects by a factor you know (say, *0.001):

- select all objects (press <kbd>A</kbd>)
- press <kbd>S</kbd>, then <kbd>.</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>1</kbd>
- then, left click to confirm.

If you want to control the scale center point in order to keep relative coordinates of the objects, you can place you 3D cursor where you want and choose *3D cursor* pivot center before scaling your objects.

Comment: Thanks, the viewport now can accommodate my object. After an `Origin to Geometry` can I center the view (and move the cursor) to my origin?

Comment: @vbence `Shift + C` to center the view on your object and `Shift + S > Cursor to selected` to snap the cursor to it.

Comment: We're getting there.. :) Now can I center the viewport too to this point?

Comment: OK I used `N` > `View` > `Lock to Object`.